# Shall we create a community wiki of world-building resources

Tags: discussion

Ok so [this questions](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/17248/recommended-book-framework-for-fantasy-worldbuilding) prompted me to think of something I feel we should have thought of a long time ago.

I think it would be a great idea to create a community wiki (or wiki's depending on how many responses we get) for world-building resources.  I'm talking:

- Books
- Websites
- Software
- you get the idea.

For example, each answer could be topic specific and broken into sections

**Sample**:

---

**Creating Magic Systems**

*Resource books and guides:*

- Book 1
- Book 2
- Book 3

*Helpful websites/communities*

- Site 1
- Site 2
- Site 3

*Useful Software*

- Program 1
- Program 2
- Program 3

*Reference material and examples*

- This section might be stories you would recommend to people as examples
- Material 2
- Material 3

---

Comment: I think this could definitely prove to be extremely beneficial! +1 because this could expand into a super valuable resource.

Comment: Yeah, this is a great idea. I bet I could find stuff there that I didn't even know I wanted.

Comment: Your thinking about a community wiki post? We could do it right here.

Answer (score 7):

Think about which of these could be done in relevant *tag wikis*.  That intrinsically links the resources with the questions most likely to benefit from them.  I've seen occasional tag wikis that are *very* thorough -- encyclopedic, even.  Let's use a structure we already have for the cases where it works; people already know about it, can edit it, etc.

Comment: Monica can you elaborate on how this would work?  I see questions on these lines getting close on the main site as answers would simply be lists of books, sites, tools or other resources?  I am not terribly familiar with how this would work..

Comment: @James to use your example, the tag wiki for the [tag:magic] tag could compile resources for designing magic systems, useful web sites, key examples of different types of magic systems, relevant software, etc.  Somebody looking at a [tag:magic] question can get to that right from the question, via the tag.  Meanwhile, somebody looking at an [tag:astronomy] question doesn't have such easy access, but also probably doesn't care.  Meanwhile, if there are *astronomy*-related resources he's got *that* tag right there... Does that help?

Comment: Yep. Sure does.  Thanks Monica.

Answer (score 0):

I am definitely down for this idea. The main benefit I could see here is that most of the major sources people would need to cite would me all in one place. I can't think of any specific examples right now, but I have seen before where several answers referenced the same source (web page or other answer on world building), so having a wiki would allow people's really good answers to be promoted there so that they don't get lost or unknowingly plagiarized.

I just found the kind of question that would benefit most from a wiki. This is the question [here](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/17010/7072).

I will add more stuff like this as I find it.